# How to limit loop to a certain number of repetitions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

In my Rails application I have this loop:

```
dates = []
loop do
  date = start_date += increment
  break if date > Date.today
  dates << date
end
```

How can I limit this loop to a certain number of repetitions?

The `start_date` is dynamic in my application and a `user` could easily bring my app to its knees by inserting e.g. `0000-00-00` there which will cause millions of repetitions.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: What do you want your limit to be? The user inserts them as `Date` objects?

Comment: Can you give a little background behind this code snippet please? It may help it suggesting, perhaps, a better solution. Thanks

Comment: Why not get the diff between the dates before the loop, and if greater than the "max" then error as @apohl suggested or just set the limit to the max.

Comment: I can't validate the user input in this particular case. It would be perfect to somehow *count* the loops and then `break` the loop when it exceeds that number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could keep a counter of the repetitions and stop the loop as soon as a threshold is reached.

For example to limit the loop to *100 iterations*:

```
dates = []
counter = 0

while counter < 100 # threshold
  date = start_date += increment
  break if date > Date.today
  dates << date
  counter += 1
end
```

Otherwise, you could only enter the loop if `start_date` is inside a certain timeframe:

```
dates = []
loop do
  date = start_date += increment
  break if date > Date.today
  dates << date
end if start_date >= Date.today - 3.months.ago
```